# github: how should I work out this issue

Tags: git

This might be complicated.

I forked a repository , create changes to commit point B , and from B , and I created some other changes , which is commit point C.

Original master --->  Commit B --->  Commit C

Since B and C doesn't interfere each other(which work on different files totally) , I'm going to send the pull request of C first.

But how ? Once I click on "Pull Request" , both B and C are sent out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new branch and cherry-pick C into it, then pull-request your new branch.